# Run script every 15 minutes 9-4 using Systemd.timer

Tags: systemd

Is there a way to configure Systemd.timer so that it runs a script every 15 minutes Mon-Fri between 9AM and 4 PM.

This is what my timer file looks like

```
[Unit]
Description=Execute every 15 minutes 9-4

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Mon-Fri *-*-* 9-16:00/15:00
Unit=job.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What does job.service look like? And what happens (or doesn't) when you enable this timer and it's service?

Answer (score 1):

The [`systemd.time`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html) `man` page does *not* suggest you can have ranges (9 to 16) for anything other than days of the week:

> Specifying two weekdays separated by "-" refers to a range of
>   continuous weekdays.

and

> In the date and time specifications [...] each component can be
>   specified as a list of values separated by commas.

So for now<sup>1</sup>, the only way to do it is to explicitly list all values:

```
OnCalendar=Mon-Fri *-*-* 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16:00/15:00
```

---

<sub>1:</sub>
As of `systemd` [version 231](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/fcd30826d4ea267563e2121b512e3cbe50aec1ca/NEWS#L31), `OnCalendar` supports using ".." to represent ranges:

```
OnCalendar=Mon..Fri 9..16:00/15
```